# ASP MVC Select statement error when trying to build dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, select, selectlistitem

The error: does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method for 'Select' accepting a first argument of.....

I seen this way used in a lot in examples, why does it hate my .select statement? I'm simply trying to build my dropdownlist and send it to the view.

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Genres
                .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Value = c.gId.ToString(),
                                    Text = c.gName
                                });
ViewBag.gId = items;
```

Answer (score 1):

> why does it hate my .select statement?

Make sure you have brought the [`.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) extension method into scope by adding the proper using directive to the top of your page:

```
using System.Linq;
```

You should probably read more about how [`extension methods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) work and LINQ in general before getting into ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: You are correct that I need to read more, and tyvm for pointing out where to start. I did the right-click thing and VS didn't tell me to load linq. But of course that was the fix. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2182715, unfortunately VS will not help you with extension methods. So if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work